# How to determine whether "and" or "or" is correct when listing excluded entities?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

As an example, a road sign might say:

> No trucks and buses

Or perhaps:

> No trucks or buses

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Those both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so simple as it first seems. The use of *or* is unambiguous: trucks or buses are excluded, whether singly or together.

The use of *and* is not so clear-cut. Its interpretation depends on context and detail. Consider:

No cars and trailers.

No mothers and buggies.

The use of the conventionally acceptable and meaningful noun phrases *cars and trailers* or *mothers and buggies* excludes neither cars nor trailers, neither mothers nor buggies.

In the case of trucks and buses, the noun phrase *trucks and buses* is not in conventional use so the sign has to be taken to exclude them singly.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you! One may be ambiguous in certain situations whereas the other ensures no ambiguity.